# Unable to mock a third party api client connection tool

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
describe ".valid_jira_build?" do

  context 'given valid build name' do
    let(:configd_client) { ('login.yml') }
    let(:client) { double(configd_client) }

    before do
     allow(YAML)
     .to receive(:load_file)
     .with('login.yml')
     .and_return(configd_client)

   allow(JenkinsApi::Client)
            .to receive(:new).with(configd_client)
            .and_return(client)
   allow(client).to receive_message_chain(:job, :status) {'success'}
 end

 it 'will return true' do
  client.stub(:job)
  expect(JenkinsClient.new('build').valid_jira_build?).to be_true
 end
end
```

I am attempting to mock JenkinsApi::Client::Job.get_latest_build_status, I have tried numerous ways to mock this but am new to RSpec and am running in to a multitude of problems. I am not wanting the Client object to reach out to a server but have failed to mock it properly to prevent this from happening.

Any help would be appreciated. The current error received from this build is:

```
1) JenkinsClient.valid_jira_build? given valid build name will return true
      Failure/Error: latest_build_status = client.job.status
                                       ("#{jira_build_to_check}")
 NoMethodError:
       undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass
     # ./lib/jenkins_client.rb:59:in `valid_jira_build?'
     # ./lib/jenkins_client.rb:30:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/jenkins_client_spec.rb:31:in `new'
     # ./spec/jenkins_client_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something more like this:

```
  let(:client) { double(JenkinsApi::Client) }
  allow(client).to receive_message_chain(:job, :status) {'success'}
  allow(JenkinsApi::Client)
    .to receive(:new).and_return(client)
```

Do you care that to test that you're pulling in the `login.yml` file?  if so, you'd want to add more doubles round the `client` stuff.

The issue, with what you have, I think, is that your `client.stub(:job)` is overriding the actual client message chain thing.  So that line should also get dumped.

Comment: `code`
.....
Finished in 0.02251 seconds (files took 1.4 seconds to load)
5 examples, 0 failures 
`code` 

Those changes have it executing. I have a few changes to make in order to get the rest of the program to execute correctly, but that fixed my mocking issues.